# How to set Validation set when training CNN on MATLAB(trainNetwork())

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, virtual-machine

I'm trying to train a CNN on MATLAB. The matlab document says that, load the data, set the layers and options. finally using trainNetwork() for training.

```
    layers = [imageInputLayer([28 28 1])
          convolution2dLayer(5,10,...
                                'Stride',1,...
                                'Padding',[0,0])
          reluLayer
          maxPooling2dLayer(2,'Stride',2)
          fullyConnectedLayer(10)
          softmaxLayer
          classificationLayer];


 options = trainingOptions('sgdm',...Environment
                            'CheckpointPath','',...
                            'ExecutionEnvironment','gpu',...                'auto'  | 'cpu' | 'gpu' | 'multi-gpu' | 'parallel'
                            'InitialLearnRate',0.0001,...   Learning Rate
                            'LearnRateSchedule','none',...                  none    |piecewise
                            'LearnRateDropPeriod',10,...
                            'LearnRateDropFactor',0.1,...
                            'L2Regularization',0.0001,...   Regularization
                            'MaxEpochs',15,...              Epochs
                            'MiniBatchSize',128,...         Batch           128     |
                            'Momentum',0.9,...                              0.9     |
                            'Shuffle','once',...                            once    |never
                            'Verbose',1,...                                 1       | 0             — Indicator to display the information on the training progress
                            'VerboseFrequency',100,...                      50      | 0 
                            'OutputFcn',@plotTrainingAccuracy);

convnet = trainNetwork(trainDigitData,layers,options);
```

below is my program for train a CNN, but the thing is I cannot find a option for setting Validation Set. And the bigger the number I set the 'epoch', the longer the time it will train. will it stop even before overfitting?

doesn't like the nnstart toolbox, when train a NN, it will show the cross-entropy and the validation, train error rate.

So, what do you usually use when train a CNN on matlab? using the 3rd party lib interface like caffe? or write program yourself?

Comment: Did you find any solution for your question?

Comment: Not Yet. I'm using the official solution provided by MATLAB give up to consider whether there is e Validation Set

Comment: There are other training options such as
ValidationData
ValidationPatience
that can help in you case.

Answer (score 0):

You may split your data to training and testing data

```
idx = floor(0.8 * height(data));
trainingData = data(1:idx,:);
testData = data(idx:end,:);
```

Then after trainNetwork, you can run the test part

```
resultsStruct = struct([]);

for i = 1:height(testData)

    % Read the image.
    I = imread(testData.imageFilename{i});
    % Run the detector.
    [bboxes, scores, labels] = detect(detector, I);

    % Collect the results.
    resultsStruct(i).Boxes = bboxes;
    resultsStruct(i).Scores = scores;
    resultsStruct(i).Labels = labels;
end

% Convert the results into a table.
results = struct2table(resultsStruct);
```

If you want to check the implementation for Faster R-CNN implementation https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/object-detection-using-faster-r-cnn-deep-learning.html